# Block main domain and sub domains direct file access with single .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, server

I want to protect direct file access to my server. i have the below code it performs well:

```
#To protect direct access

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?maindomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(xls|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

I want to protect subdomains like test.maindomain.com, blog.maindomain.com, 
1) how can i do that with above code?
2) do i need to put this code in every subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this rule to block both domains:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !https?://(www\.|test\.|blog\.)?maindomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:xls|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: its working if i removed `\` before .com and `$` after the .com

Comment: Oh yes that's right since `HTTP_REFERER` is much longer URI, fixed in answer now. Thanks.